# Undefined is not an object in react navigation props

Tags: android, react-native

Here this is my app.js

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login:{ screen: Login  },
  DrawerNav: {  screen: DrawerNavigator },
})

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <AppStackNavigator/>
    )
  }
}

export default createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);
```

And this is DrawerNavigator.js file

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Icon name = "menu" onPress={() =>  this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}/>
          </Left>
        </Header>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Button
            title="Toggle"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Button
          title="Toggle Drawer"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const CustomDrawerComponent = (props)=>(
  <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={{height:150, backgroundColor:'white', alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <Image source={require('./logo.png')} style={{height:120, width:120, borderRadius:60}} />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView> )


const navigator =  createDrawerNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {drawerLabel: 'HomeScreen',}
  },

  SettingsScreen: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {drawerLabel: 'SettingsScreen',}
  }},
  {   
    drawerPosition :"left",   contentComponent:CustomDrawerComponent
  });

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

And this is login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }


  static navigationOptions = {
    title:'Welcome',
    headerLeft: 
      <View style={{paddingLeft:16}}>
        <Icon
          name="md-menu"
          size={30}
          color='black'
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} />
      </View>
  }


  loginHandler= ()=>{
    //this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerNav')
    this.props.navigation.openDrawer()
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Button
            title={'Login'}
            onPress={this.loginHandler.bind(this)}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Now Whenever i click icon to open navigation drawer then error arises undefined is not an object (evaluating _this2.props.navigation).I have tried many possible ways but i couldnt solve this problem.How can i solve this ? I have registered login component inside stack navigator then also login component was not able access navigation props.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
```

Error describes that this line inside static block in login.js contains error

Comment: You don't have access to `this` in static properties. `navigationOptions` can be a function that accepts an object: `{ navigation, navigationOptions, screenProps }`. You can use `navigation` to navigate

Comment: EDIT: actually Krizzy is correct, maybe changing your navigation options to this will work: navigationOptions: ({ navigation }). And then onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}

Comment: same error arises when calling loginHandler method also

Comment: i tried what krizzy told but same problem persists